# Android onItemLongClick show progress bar only on current item

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

progress bar only on current item, not on others.
when i long clicking on item the progress bar shown on to or more items and changing position.
i want show progressbar only on clicked item not other items

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

                String getidtoextra = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wallid)).getText().toString();
                final ProgressBar itemprogress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.itemprogress);
                itemprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                DownloadManager manager = new DownloadManager();
                String destPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Kaghaz Divari/" + getidtoextra + "_KD.jpg";
                DownloadRequest request = new DownloadRequest()
                        .setDownloadId(pos)
                        .setUrl("http://www.wenenus.com/www.samankd.com/android/wallpaper/download.php?id=" + getidtoextra)
                        .setDestFilePath(destPath)
                        .setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStart(int downloadId, long totalBytes) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onRetry(int downloadId) {
                                itemprogress.setProgress(0);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(int downloadId, long bytesWritten, long totalBytes) {
                                itemprogress.setProgress((int) ((bytesWritten * 100) / totalBytes));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int downloadId, String filePath) {
                                itemprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int downloadId, int statusCode, String errMsg) {
                                itemprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                manager.add(request);
                return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
            }
        });
```

My custom adapter

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null) inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        ImageView thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        ImageView isdownloaded = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isdownloaded);
        LinearLayout newwallpaperarea = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newwallpaperarea);
        TextView downloads = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dlstxt);
        TextView rating = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingtxt);
        TextView wallid = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.wallid);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        File is_wall_dl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Kaghaz Divari/"+m.getThumbnailUrl());
        File is_wall_dl_id = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Kaghaz Divari/"+m.getId()+"_KD.jpg");

        if(is_wall_dl.exists() || is_wall_dl_id.exists()){
            isdownloaded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            isdownloaded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        String tsnew = ts+"000";
        long realtime = Long.parseLong(tsnew);

        String walldate = m.getDate();
        long walldateall = Long.parseLong(walldate);
        long walldatefinal = walldateall+86400000;

        if (realtime > walldatefinal) {
            newwallpaperarea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            newwallpaperarea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // thumbnail image
        Ion.with(thumbNail)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.skd_small_bg_200x200)
                .error(R.drawable.skd_small_bg_200x200_error)
                .load("http://www.wenenus.com/www.samankd.com/android/wallpaper/wallpaper/200/200/80/1/" + m.getThumbnailUrl());
        downloads.setText(m.getDownloads());
        rating.setText(m.getRating());
        wallid.setText(m.getId());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: onItemLongClick () has an int called "pos", this is the one you have selected.

Comment: Use <ProgressBar> in your list item and set it visibility gone. When you long press on list item then show it.